# How to Use a Python Script for Authentication in ocserv?

Tags: python

I am trying to set up ocserv with external script authentication. However, it seems that my configuration is not working properly. I have added the following lines to the `ocserv.conf` file:

```
auth = "external-script /path/to/my/script.py"
```

And my authentication script (`script.py`) looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

def authenticate(username, password):
    # Custom authentication logic here
    if username == "user" and password == "pass":
        print("Auth-Type: Accept")
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print("Auth-Type: Reject")
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: {} <username> <password>".format(sys.argv[0]))
        sys.exit(1)

    username, password = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
    authenticate(username, password)
```

Despite this, it seems that ocserv is not utilizing my script for authentication. Can someone guide me on how to correctly use an external script for authentication in ocserv? Are there any specific configurations or considerations I am missing?
Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: chmod +x /path/to/my/script.py

Comment: Feb 25 13:19:06 Test ocserv[14373]: note: skipping 'pid-file' config option     
 Feb 25 13:19:06 Test ocserv[14373]: error: vhost:default: unknown or unsupported
  auth method: external-script /etc/ocserv/script.py                             
 Feb 25 13:19:06 Test systemd[1]: ocserv.service: Main process exited, code=exite